# Request Pipeline Asp.net API with Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, owin

I am trying to simulate a request pipeline using asp.net api and owin self host. I want to be able to do stuff before a request hits a method on the api controller and after the method executes. Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might still be able to use action filters: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: Also:  When you say "ASP.NET api" -- do you mean Web API?

Comment: I do, thanks for the response.. looks like action filters should do the trick.